# BasePresenter, BaseView how to approach the problem with clean solution

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : BaseView>{
    private lateinit var view : T

    fun attachView(view : T) {
        this.view = view
    }

    fun getView() = view
}
```

With this approach, I have to write `presenter.attachView(this)` each time, in an Activity, which produces boiler code:

```
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity(), SplashActivityView {
    @Inject
    lateinit var splashActivityPresenter: SplashActivityPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        splashActivityPresenter.attachView(this)

        splashActivityPresenter.getUser()
    }
}
```

How can I solve it so that my Activities automatically call the `attachView()` in `onCreate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem. You must give to your presenter a **concrete instance** of the activity / fragment. Therefore, the call attachView() must be written every time.

Comment: So this isn't against a clean code approach ? I feel like writing it for each activity is a kind of bad thing , that's why I was thinking if there is a way to make it generic

Comment: @trOnk12 Right, this isn't against a clean code approach. This refers to the features of Android framework.